# Unable to boot in to Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu & Mint

Tags: grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu & Mint on my system, but now I can't boot in to Windows 10.
I've attempted to use boot-repair from a Live USB, but I still can't boot in.

As far as I can tell, the installation is on the sda13

With the following http://paste.ubuntu.com/25865742/ can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: You show the same UUID, but different GUID(partUUID) on sda1 and sdb1 - 67E3-17ED. Do not know Mac, but on a PC that is not allowed as UUID must be unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

It's a UEFI system which means you can always access Windows by selecting "Windows boot manager" in the UEFI settings.

In order to have Windows added to the Grub menu, **first you need to decide which one, Ubuntu or Mint, you want in control of Grub**. Then boot the chosen distro, open a Terminal, and run `sudo update-grub`.

Additional information:

[UEFI (Ubuntu Community document)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)